# Footer overlapping with content on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to fix this issue for a friend. The website looks normal on a desktop, but when resized down to a mobile size, the footer overlaps with the content, where the footer doesn't stay at the very bottom of the page.

I've tried to play around inside inspector and CSS settings but nothing seems to work. Not sure what's going on.

Website: http://www.ijc.com.au/

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your content is in table layout, please try to remove the height given to the table. please find the attached image[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check line number 652 on http://www.ijc.com.au/css/media-queries.css
Add height auto, you havent update the height on the table for the mobile devices.

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    height: auto;
}
```

The above-mentioned CSS will fix the issue with the footer on the website.